# selecting data based on index values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, numpy

I have `three` column data saved in `inp.dat`

```
1.0   2.0   5.0 
2.0   3.0   6.0 
3.0   4.0   8.0 
4.0   1.0   7.0 
5.0   2.0   8.0 
5.0   2.0   8.0
1.0   2.0   5.0 
2.0   3.0   6.0
```

Additionally,A particular `index` value is provided for each column i.e. for column `1` index value is `3`, for column `2` index value is `4`, and for column `3` index value is `4` which is depicted as `index_value=[3,4,4]`. I want to select data `2` index values before and `2` index values after the given `index` values in the `list`, and all others values to be `zero`.

The expected output should be saved as `file.out` as shown below.

```
0.0   0.0   0.0 
2.0   0.0   0.0 
3.0   4.0   8.0 
4.0   1.0   7.0 
5.0   2.0   8.0 
5.0   2.0   8.0
0.0   2.0   5.0 
0.0   0.0   0.0
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data=np.loadtxt("inp.dat")
print(data.shape)

index_value=[3,4,4]

for i,data in enumerate(data):
    print(i,data)
    data=data[index_value[0]-2:index_value[0]+2]
np.savetxt('file.out',data)
```

I am not getting expected output using my trial code.Moreover I want to apply it to many columns of data in future. As I am a beginner I hope experts may help me overcoming this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply your task column by column while looping through your `index_list` at the same time with `zip`. Then use a mask to set several values to `0`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.dat',header=None, sep='\s+')
#this is only how I read the data to get the same example data you showed us
print(df)

     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  5.0
1  2.0  3.0  6.0
2  3.0  4.0  8.0
3  4.0  1.0  7.0
4  5.0  2.0  8.0
5  5.0  2.0  8.0
6  1.0  2.0  5.0
7  2.0  3.0  6.0

index_list = [3, 4, 4]

for target_idx, col in zip(index_list, df.columns):
    
    mask = (df.index >= target_idx-2) & (df.index < target_idx + 3)
    # for the first column mask looks like this:
    # [False  True  True  True  True  True False False]
    
    df.loc[~mask, col] = 0 # set all values NOT in the mask to 0

print(df)

     0    1    2
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  2.0  0.0  0.0
2  3.0  4.0  8.0
3  4.0  1.0  7.0
4  5.0  2.0  8.0
5  5.0  2.0  8.0
6  0.0  2.0  5.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0

#If you like to save it:
df.to_csv('file.out',header=False, index=False, sep='\t')
```

Comment: In reality i have thousands of column where it is not possible to write manually this line names='col1 col2 col3.............'.split()  can u make it automatic

Comment: no need for it. that was just for me reading in the data. If `header=None` and no `names` defined, then pandas will just name them numerical, starting with 0,1,2 and so on. in the loop itself we just call `df.columns`, so you also don't need to know/write down any names for the columns. I can change my answer if you want ?

Comment: if possible please update it @Rabinzel.Thanks

Comment: I did. Since you will go through all columns back to back you don't need to worry about their names. Be aware that your `index_list` should be as long as the number of your columns. if this list is shorter, not all columns get applied with the mask.